# Using Collections on Amazon's Manage Content and Devices

Tags: kindle

I've created some Collections on Amazon's Manage Content and Devices on my PC. Now what? I don't see any way to sort or select books by a particular Collection. Lots and lots of info  on how to create. Nothing on how to actually use.